# Sql: Using alias in nested queries

Tags: mysql

```
select
    user.name,
    (select department.name
     from profile, degree, department
     where user.profile_id=profile.id
     and profile.degree_id=degree.id
     and degree.department_id=department.id) DEPT_NAME
from user, query
where user.id=query.user_id as USER_NAME
order by user.name;
```

This is the query I have written.In this for department.name the column alias changed to DEPT_NAME but for user.name it doesn't changes, it throws error.. Please help...

Comment: what is error throws....

Comment: why write you alias in where clause?

Comment: just write `select user.name as USER_NAME ...` for result field aliasing

Comment: I tried.. But it doesn't works...

Comment: Are you get `mutiple results in subquery` error? add `limit 1` to it

Answer (score 0):

Move your alias to fields clause:

```
select
    `user`.name as USER_NAME,
    (select department.name
     from profile, degree, department
     where `user`.profile_id=profile.id
     and profile.degree_id=degree.id
     and degree.department_id=department.id LIMIT 1) DEPT_NAME
from `user`, query
where `user`.id=query.user_id
order by `user`.name;
```

Also your query is too heavy, try to change it and check difference:

```
select u.name USER_NAME, dp.name DEPT_NAME
from `user` u
inner join query       q on  u.id = q.user_id
left  join profile     p on  p.id = u.profile_id
left  join degree      d on  d.id = p.degree_id
left  join department dp on dp.id = d.department_id
order by u.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

try it-

```
SELECT usr.name User_Name,(SELECT dt.name FROM profile pf,degree dg,department dt WHERE usr.profile_id=pf.id AND pf.degree_id=dg.id AND dg.department_id=dt.id limit 1)DEPT_NAME FROM USER usr, QUERY qry WHERE usr.id=qry.user_id ORDER BY usr.name;
```

Even you can use below query which can be fast-

```
SELECT user.name user_name,department.name AS DEPT_NAME 
FROM profile,degree,department,`user`,`query` 
WHERE user.profile_id=profile.id AND profile.degree_id=degree.id AND degree.department_id=department.id AND user.id=query.user_id ORDER BY user.name;
```

Comment: I want to change column alias of user.name to USER_NAME. Please help

Comment: check i have added now.

Comment: Are you really think, that cross join through all tables can be fast?

Comment: I am not getting any error..but column name of user.name doesn't changes to USER.NAME

Comment: i have done some changed in first query also, please verify it...regarding your query related with cross join it will depend how much data is fetching your query, so you have to check which one is fast...

Comment: may i know reason of -ve voting, so that i can improve my answer...@sundaresh: both suggested query will provide you desired results.

Comment: sorry sir i am new to this site..I don't know about that.I click on that without my knowledge.Please don't mistake me...

Comment: click on upvote to remove -ve rating and you can again upvote if this helps you but its your choice... :)